# My Toast doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-toast

I don't know why but the toast doesn't appear when I run the program. This is my code:

```
class Number {

    int number;
    public boolean isSquare() {

        double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(number);
        if (squareRoot==Math.floor(squareRoot)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isTriangular() {

        int x = 1;
        int triangularNumber = 1;
        while(triangularNumber<number) {
            x++;
            triangularNumber = triangularNumber + x;
        }

        if (triangularNumber == number) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public void idButton (View view) {

    EditText inputNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNumber);

    Number myNumber = new Number();
    myNumber.number = Integer.parseInt(inputNumber.getText().toString());

    String message = "";
    if (myNumber.isSquare()){
        if (myNumber.isTriangular()){
            message = myNumber.number + " your number is triangular and square";
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

After compiling there's no error in the code, please guide me what should be improved on the code since I'm still beginner. Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is there entirely no Toast or is it just empty?

Comment: there is entirely no toast appear

Comment: could you please post the code, where you call your idButton() method?

Comment: I found the problem, I haven't correctly connected the connected with On Click on the button

Answer (score 0):

```
String message = "";
if (myNumber.isSquare()){
    if (myNumber.isTriangular()){
        message = myNumber.number + " your number is triangular and square";
    }
}
```

In this code, you haven't write any else statement. What if the number is neither square nor triangular? In both of these scenerios you will get an empty message as you have declared message = "";
So write your code as

```
String message = "";
    if (myNumber.isSquare()){
        if (myNumber.isTriangular()){
            message = message+myNumber.number + " your number is triangular and square";
        }
        else
        {
            message = message+"No triangular";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        message = message+"No square";
    }
```

Comment: I tested the code with inserting number 1, which should be triangular dan square but still no toast appear

Comment: I found the problem, I haven't correctly connected the connected with On Click on the button